# Update an object of object in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using node.js and mongoose and I have a problem.
Here is my model that i'm using:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const prodSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  rate: String,
  rate_number: String,
  type: String,
  offers: {
    netflix: {
      url: String,
    },
    amz: {
      url: String,
    },
  },
  updated_at: Date,
}, {
  collection: 'prod',
});

const ProdModel = mongoose.model('prod', prodSchema);

module.exports = ProdModel;
```

For exemple I would like to set the netflix url and after set the amz url.

```
ProdModel.updateOne({ name: currentName },{ offers: { amz: { url: movies[i].url } } });
```

But when i want for exemple to set the netflix url amz return an empty Object :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating nested object in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832921/updating-nested-object-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mongo [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator to update nested properties without overriding other properties in the parent object.

```
ProdModel.updateOne({ name: currentName }, { $set: { "offers.netflix.url": movies[i].url } });
```