# Modifying an object with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need help with `mongoose` please.
I would like to modify in an object, but I don't know how to do it.
Can someone help me please?

PS : `ActorId` return 1

I have tried :

```
const user = await userModel.updateOne({ ActorId: ActorId }, { "Mood.FigureAnimation": request.mood.FigureAnimation, "Mood.FaceAnimation": request.mood.FaceAnimation, "Mood.MouthAnimation": request.mood.MouthAnimation, "Mood.MoodText": request.mood.TextLine });
```

Here is my request :

```
{
  mood: {
    ActorId: 1,
    FigureAnimation: 'stand',
    FaceAnimation: 'neutral',
    MouthAnimation: 'none',
    TextLine: 'hello',
    SpeechLine: false
  },
  TicketHeader: {
    Ticket: '1,1621847572744,SECRET'
  }
}
```

Here is my Shema :

```
Mood: {
  FigureAnimation: String,
  FaceAnimation: String,
  MouthAnimation: String,
  TextLine: String
}
```

[Here is my DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz0vE.png)

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Comment: const user = await userModel.updateOne({ ActorId: ActorId }, {$set:{ "Mood.FigureAnimation": request.mood.FigureAnimation, "Mood.FaceAnimation": request.mood.FaceAnimation, "Mood.MouthAnimation": request.mood.MouthAnimation, "Mood.MoodText": request.mood.TextLine }});

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating nested object in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832921/updating-nested-object-in-mongoose)