# How do I partially update a nested schema in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

EDIT:
After trying many different approaches i found a working solution that maps any object to a format that mongoose understands. See solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69547021/17426304

```
const updateNestedObjectParser = (nestedUpdateObject) => {
    const final = {

    }
    Object.keys(nestedUpdateObject).forEach(k => {
        if (typeof nestedUpdateObject[k] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(nestedUpdateObject[k])) {
            const res = updateNestedObjectParser(nestedUpdateObject[k])
            Object.keys(res).forEach(a => {
                final[`${k}.${a}`] = res[a]
            })
        }
        else
            final[k] = nestedUpdateObject[k]
    })
    return final
}
```

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have a mongoose structure of

```js
    ChildSchema = {
      childProperty: String,
      childProperty2: String
    }

    MainSchema = {
      mainProperty: String,
      mainProperty2: String,
      child: childSchema
    }
```

In my update function I want to pass a partial object of `mainSchema` and only update the properties I pass to the function.
This works fine for direct properties on my `mainSchema` but not on my `childSchema`. It overwrites the whole child property with the partial object given by my request.

So my update object looks something like this

```js
const updates = {
   child: {
      childProperty2: 'Example2'
   }
}
```

How can I only update the childProperty2 without deleting the `childProperty`?
In this example it would be easy to just update every property alone but the real world objects are much bigger and can be nested into multiple levels.

I tried to use destructuring but it does not seem to work

```js
const example = MainSchema.findOne({_id})
if (updates.child) example.child = {...example.child, ...updates.child} // Does not work
```

Is there a solution to that in mongoose (6.0)?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```js
const updates = {
  "child.childProperty2": 'Example2'
}
```

Comment: Is there a more abstract method of doing this? This approach works but requires a giant amount of manual work since there are many places where I´d need to change this.
So is there maybe a function to map any object to your given format?